# Best practices on Token ICO launch

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, security, tokens, ico

I'm trying to understand how exactly the pre-ICO/ICO should be structured in terms of technical aspect. What are there trustworthy things that every ICO developer should think about.

I'm interested in token based approach based on ethereum using ERC20 standard.
I have seen a couple of projects:

https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ico

https://github.com/airalab/

Please let me know if you can provide a very detailed answer on best practices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can add to your list the **[Open Zeppelin](http://openzeppelin.org)**. It contains some secure contracts with best practices. We will use some of their contracts during our project's called ["Jincor" ICO](http://ico.jincor.com)

Returning to your question I would like to say that there are no "The Right Way" of doing ICO from technical side. Just because it's very different from business side) [There are some best practises](https://github.com/ConsenSys/smart-contract-best-practices) which you can find on Github.

I'd also like to suggest you to go through the source code of contracts of ICO's you personally like.

Comment: *"There are some best practises which you can find on Github."* Can you add links to these best practises you're referencing?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I edited reply but I didn't mean something concrete initially

Comment: That's cool, I think the repo is a good link, it just backs up your claim of "best practices on github" `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Related:

- [Where to find ICO contract with linear / logarithmic decrease?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21548/where-to-find-ico-contract-with-linear-logarithmic-decrease)
- Reverse shameless plug: https://github.com/rstormsf/awesome-crowdsales *(linking to your repo)*

Here are some good resources too:

- http://theicohandbook.com
- http://astralship.org/ico *(back in May I read every single piece of content out there)*

This is another great article / tutorial:

- https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/how-to-create-token-and-initial-coin-offering-contracts-using-truffle-openzeppelin-1b7a5dae99b6

I'm worried your question is too generic.

I'm actually working on IDEAL ICO contract - one feature that I'm missing currently are multiple of financing. Currently a workaround would be to preserve something in region of 40% of total token supply and burn if not required.