# Where to find ICO contract with linear / logarithmic decrease?

Tags: tokens, presale, ico

I had a look at some existing crowdsale contracts:

- https://github.com/aragon/aragon-network-token/blob/master/contracts/AragonTokenSale.sol
- https://github.com/sonm-io/presale-token/blob/master/contracts/PresaleToken.sol
- https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens/tree/master/Token_Contracts/contracts
- https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts/crowdsale
- https://github.com/Giveth/minime/blob/master/contracts/MiniMeToken.sol
- https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ico/tree/master/contracts
- Etheroll: https://etherscan.io/address/0xa9a8108994bb704261567e53b49607a73876ddf1#code

Below is an ASCII graph from Aragon source code. Rather than stages, I'd like to find a contract that implements **linear or logarithmic decrease** in the amount of tokens...

[image]

Comment: For the first time I've used `rollback` function to undo the edit - full URL to **github** is much more informative than some *formatted* link.

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose we have `M` the maximum amount of tokens to sell, `I` the initial price of each token and `F` the final price of each token. Let's call `f` the function that gives the price of each token, we know that `f(0) = I` and `f(M) = F`. If you want a linear price then `f(x) = I + (F - I) * x  / M`.

The problem is to determine how many token we will get when we pay `V` and there's already `K` tokens sold. Let's say we will get `D` tokens, we know our initial price will be `f(K)` and the final prize `f(K + D)`, and the total price will be the are under the graph. Yeah math!

[image: Token price function of the emited tokens]

So we will have the equation

[image: Cost of D tokens from K]

To determine the amount of tokens to sell for `V` ethers we have to solve the 2nd degree equation `(F-I)D`<sup>2</sup>`+ 2(MI + (F-I)K)D - 2MV = 0`. Yeah, more math!

[image: (-b +/- sqrt(b^2 - 4ac))/(2a)]

For example in the plot I've `I=100, F=225, M=500`. Then when there are `K=150` for 1000 ethers we will get:

```
D = (-2*(50000+125*k)+sqrt(4*(50000+125*k)**2 + 500000*v))/250 = 7.225268630201346
```

(the other solution for D is negative)

If we want to purchase 10 token when 150 were sold already we have to pay (K=150, D=10)

```
V = ID + (F-I)*(2KD + D^2)/(2M)
V = 1000 + 125*(20*150 + 100)/1000
V = 1387.5
```

To calculate the total recaudation we set K=0, D=500

```
V = 100*500 + 125*(500^2)/(2*500)
V = 81250.0
```

We can verify this is the area of the plot.

Answer (score 1):

Solidity code based on the solution by @Ismael, 
assumes linear increase in price.

```
// tokens sold
uint256 tokensSold;
// tokens to be sold in total

uint tokensToBeSold = 100000000*(10**18);
uint ip = 5000;
uint fp = 10000;
// final price - initial price
uint256 pd = fp - ip;
// total supply * initial price
uint256 tsip = tokensToBeSold * ip;

// helper token emission functions
function howMany(uint256 value) public returns (uint256){
    uint256 a = sqrt(4 * ((tsip + pd * tokensSold) ** 2) + value.mul(8 * pd * tokensToBeSold));
    uint256 b = 2 * (tsip + pd* tokensSold);
    uint256 c = 2 * pd;

    // get a result with
    return round(((a - b)* 10) / c);
}

// Rounding function for the first decimal
function round(uint x) internal returns (uint y) {
    uint z = x % 10;

    if (z < 5) {
        return x / 10;
    }

    else {
        return (x / 10) + 1;
    }
}

// Squareroot implementation
function sqrt(uint x) internal returns (uint y) {
    uint z = (x + 1) / 2;
    y = x;
    while (z < y) {
        y = z;
        z = (x / z + z) / 2;
    }
}
```