# How to set token vesting values?

Tags: solidity

How to link token vesting with crowdsale?

Comment: Hi there. Can you be a bit more specific with your question? It's currently not clear what you're asking. (See: [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)]

Answer (score 1):

**It's a generic and broad question.**

See related question: [Where to find ICO contract with linear / logarithmic decrease?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21548/where-to-find-ico-contract-with-linear-logarithmic-decrease)

See existing crowdsale contract: https://github.com/aragon/aragon-network-token/blob/master/contracts/AragonTokenSale.sol

You probably need to hire a professional / contractor / freelancer to implement required features specifically for you.

---

Longer term - Ethereum ICO regulators investors VCs may come up with some sort of a "golden standard" related to crowdsales, I put some "must haves" in a Google Doc: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EhOGGMuyhmmfvyOnexBxYSa54RmjNyq86tZcAVaOqfw/edit#